# is that possible to pass(POST) below JSON to REST endpoint?

Tags: apex, json, rest

I saw that we can't pass the `Map<String,List<String>>` to REST post method. So I decided to go with the json as like below. Will REST allow to post this similar json to REST?

```
{
    'Emp01' : 'XXXX',
    'PermissionSetName' : { 'PermissionSet1:True',
                            'Permissionset2:False'}
    },
    {
        'Emp02' : 'XXXX',
        'PermissionSetName' : { 'PermissionSet1:False',
                                'Permissionset2:False'}
    }   
}
```

Comment: Please add one more { backet, so that JSON format gets correct first. Try & let me know

Answer (score 2):

Send a proper json to handle or  normalise it in server side

Eg.

send json like below format

```
{
"status": "Pending",
"listName": "Signed Confis",
"deal": "R23WDS23FEWS32WQS",
"notes": "",
"contacts": [
    {"con": "23EWDD23RD23","primary": true},
    {"con": "1D12EDX23D33","primary": false}
]}
```

Server side

```
public without sharing class YourClassName { 

    public class FormData {
        public String status;
        public String listName;
        public String deal;
        public String notes;
        public ContactObj[] contacts;       
    }

    public static String[] saveAddInvestorDeal(String jsonStr){
       FormData data = (FormData) JSON.deserialize(jsonStr, YourClassName.FormData.class);      
       Opportunity opp = [Select RecordType.Name from Opportunity where id=:data.deal][0];
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't you think that class and method should be `global`. And also have some `urlMapping` and `@HttpPost`. If you could add that, then it would be much better.